# Change Multiple attributes on mouse over

Tags: javascript, attributes, mouseover

Okay so I have several background images i want to display depending on an event. I am trying to change the attributes of an id and for some reason the page goes white onmouseover and nothing hapens it just loads forever.

here is the javascript functions i am using (which after research should work):

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function open(){document.getElementById('Wings').setAttribute('style', 'background: url(./wingsOpen.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index:-5');
   }

function glow(){document.getElementById('Wings').setAttribute('style', 'background: url(./wingsOpenGlow.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;  z-index:-5 ');
                }

 function close(){document.getElementById('Wings').setAttribute('style',    'background: url(./wingsClosed.png); background-repat: no-repeat;  z-index:2');
 }
  </script>
```

here is the HTML:

```
<div id="Wings" onmouseover="open()" onmouseout="open()"></div>
```

there is a search bar that the image is hiding i don't know if that is a issue or not. the glow() function is used onfocus with the search bar so that the image changes when the search bar recieves the focus

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want to write `<div id="Wings" onmouseover="open()" onmouseout="close()"></div>`?

Comment: no i want the wings open. then they glow when the search bar in the wings gets the focus.. and then close when the search bar loses the focus (onblur="sript"). However I am having another problem.. i am using this code to manipulate the z-index of the div. the close has a greater index then the search bar div. so that the searchbar is hidden and the open has a negative value z-index.. when i get them to open using onmouseover="this.id='wingsOpen';" the searchbar is visible but i am unable to activate it. which gives me another idea i will try to implement.